# counter of first occurrence of unique values of another column pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Given an example df like below, I want to find a increment counter of all unique instances of `val`. The closest that I've gotten is `df.groupby('val').cumcount()` but obviously this isn't what I want.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'val': [100, 101, 104, 104, 106, 108, 108, 108]})
```

Desired result:

```
    val ctr
0   100 1
1   101 2
2   104 3
3   104 0
4   106 4
5   108 5
6   108 0
7   108 0
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use [`groupby ngroup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html) to enumerate groups (`sort=False`) if wanting groups enumerated the way the appear in the DataFrame, then [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) out the [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) values:

```
s = df.groupby('val', sort=False).ngroup() + 1  # Get unique group number
df['ctr'] = s.mask(s.duplicated(), 0)  # Add in the 0s
```

`df`:

```
   val  ctr
0  100    1
1  101    2
2  104    3
3  104    0
4  106    4
5  108    5
6  108    0
7  108    0
```

Or with [`pd.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) and [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to assign [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) values to 0:

```
import numpy as np

m = df['val'].duplicated()
df['ctr'] = np.where(m, 0, pd.factorize(df['val'])[0] + 1)
```

`df`:

```
   val  ctr
0  100    1
1  101    2
2  104    3
3  104    0
4  106    4
5  108    5
6  108    0
7  108    0
```

Comment: Yours is more generic!  +1

Comment: It always depends :) You're is faster if the right conditions are met.

Answer (score 1):

If your sequence of 'Val` are in sorted order, you can use:

```
m = df['val'].ne(df['val'].shift())

df['ctr'] = np.where(m, m.cumsum(), 0)
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

   val  ctr
0  100    1
1  101    2
2  104    3
3  104    0
4  106    4
5  108    5
6  108    0
7  108    0
```